# SQL WHERE IN Subquery returns comma-separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a field in a SQL table (Locations) whose value is a semi-colon separated list:

```
username1;username2;username3
```

If I say:

```
SELECT '''' + REPLACE(owners, ';', ''',''') + '''' FROM Locations WHERE ...
```

I can get it to output:

```
'username1','username2','username3'
```

... but what I want to do is then use that in a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName IN (   
    SELECT '''' + REPLACE(owners, ';', ''',''') + '''' 
    FROM Locations WHERE ...
)
```

So, essentially I want the output of that subquery to act as a string in the IN() clause. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Sorry ... Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: how about splitting the string into a table?

Comment: Every time I search for SQL Split, I get all kinds of different answers that usually involve writing a custom SQL function - something I'm not certain I can do within the CMS I'm using. But if there is another way to do that inline, great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't do what you are trying to do, construct `'username1','username2','username3'` at runtime.

yet a simpler solution would be to use a split function

### Split function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
  @delimited nvarchar(max),
  @delimiter nvarchar(100)
) 
RETURNS @t TABLE (id int identity(1,1), val nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
  declare @xml xml
  set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@delimited,@delimiter,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

  insert into @t(val)
  select
    r.value('.','varchar(max)') as item
  from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)

  RETURN
END
```

### Query

```
SELECT *
FROM [Users] u 
WHERE u.UserName IN (  SELECT val 
                       FROM [Location] l
                                    CROSS APPLY [dbo].[Split](l.owners, ';')
                    );
```

Comment: When SQL-Server Team decided to introduce XML it was a great day for SQL developers. XML is a goodie in any case, but all these "tricks" you can use it for are even better. Thx for this..

Answer (score 0):

If the inner select returns only one row you can use CHARINDEX:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE CHARINDEX(''''+UserName+'''', (
   SELECT '''' + REPLACE(owners, ';', ''',''') + '''' 
   FROM Locations WHERE ...
)) > 0
```

Comment: This works but will be horribly bad for performance on a large dataset.

Comment: You mean the data in Users table? Will the database use any index when using abovementioned Split function?

Comment: The split function runs once and produces a rowset, which is then `JOIN`ed using a normal equijoin, and can thus take advantage of an index, no problem! The query you proposed is clever and works, but requires evaluating a string-returning expression *once for every row* and thus by nature is non-sargable.

Comment: I mean index on a rowset created by a function, is that possible? But I agree that the inner select has to processed many times in my solution.

Comment: No, the function has no index, but it wouldn't benefit from one in most cases, because the number of values is very small. Unless the rowset-producing function was going to return dozens of pages, a scan would be superior to any indexed method.